# Insert array to MySQL in node.js?

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js

How can I insert an array to a table in MySQL with nodejs? The code below works if the array is just one, but if there is more items in the array, I get the error: *"ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW"*

I need to insert all the array values in the table. How can I achieve this?

Here is what I got so far:

```
        let workoutArray = [];

        result.forEach(function(name) {
            workoutArray.push(name.exercise);
        });

    let sql2 = 'INSERT INTO reps (email, date, workout, exercise) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
    connection.query(sql2, [user, addDate, workoutToIndex, workoutArray], function (error2, result2) { 
            if (error2) throw error2;
            console.log(result2);
    });


        response.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending an array as a parameter, try sending an array from an array.

Example:

```
    let workoutArray = [];

    result.forEach(function(name) {
        workoutArray.push(name.exercise);
    });

let sql2 = 'INSERT INTO reps (email, date, workout, exercise) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
connection.query(sql2, [[user, addDate, workoutToIndex, workoutArray]], function (error2, result2) { 
        if (error2) throw error2;
        console.log(result2);
});


    response.end();
});
```

Comment: clever idea, but it gives me a syntax error: "ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax"